# Can someone explain to me what python is doing here?

Tags: python

```
>>> 3 > 2 == True
 False  #say what?
>>> (3 > 2) == True
 True
>>> 3 > (2 == True)
 True
>>> 3 > 1 == True
 True
>>> 3 > False
 True
```

What is Python doing in its godforsaken hidden logics that makes that first statement `False`, while the rest are `True`?

Comment: Comparison chaining doesn't work the way you think it does. See the third paragraph here: http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in

Comment: And `1 == True` is True because `bool` is a subclass of `int` and `True == 1` and `False == 0`. Which is also why `3 > True` is true, and `0 < True` is true, but `0 > False` is not..

Comment: Also, I don't know if you're making this mistake, but a common mistake is to do something akin to `if 3 > 2 == True:`, when they mean `if 3 > 2:`.  You'll almost never want to test if something explicitly `== True` in python.

Comment: @Neftas: No, only `0 == False` is true. Every other number is *not* equal to `False`.

Comment: This was for a lecture, I was explaining the different comparison operators. What I meant was the second line (3>2) == True, just to show them what *can* be done.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a chained comparison (see [here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#not-in) in the docs), the same way that

```
>>> 1 < 2 < 3
True
```

is

```
>>> (1 < 2) and (2 < 3)
True
```

In this case, we have

```
>>> 3 > 2 == True
False
```

because

```
>>> (3 > 2) and (2 == True)
False
```

because

```
>>> (3 > 2), (2 == True)
(True, False)
```

Comment: And `1 == True` is true because `bool` is a subclass of `int`.

Comment: And `3 > True` is true for the same reasons.

Comment: Well said @DSM. Thanks much. Hooray for python playing fast and loose with the rules of precedence for the sake of a minor convenience!

Comment: @Andrew: glad to help.  But respectfully, if you haven't seen this before, you haven't used Python enough in real programs to decide whether or not the convenience is worth it.  FWIW I find it so.